# The sequence 1, 4, 9, 16,...

Tags: recurrence-relations, pattern-recognition

For a given pattern (1,4,9,16..)

What is the value for the *nth* number in the series and what is the pattern?

We have a difference in opinion with my son's 5th grade math teacher and want to get consensus.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the difference of opinion?  This seems obviously to be the list of perfect squares.

Comment: The teacher was using the recursive way referenced below to represent the sequence and given that we were struggling to get to the nth number. Using the list of perfect squares the answer was obvious.

Comment: Ah.  Of course, those two expressions describe the same sequence.  Worth noting that not all recursively defined sequences have pleasant closed formulas, so it is worth seeing both approaches.

Answer (score 2):

This is the following succession:
$$a_n=n^2$$.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_1=1$$

$$a_n=a_{n-1}+(2n-1)$$

is a recursive way of representing the sequence of squares.

Comment: @GuyFsone This might be one of the representations that have caused a 'difference in opinion' as stated by the OP. Adding consecutive odd numbers just might be the other way of writing sequence of squares that led to this.

Comment: @GuyFsone My answer helped. Check out the comments on the OP. Not a low quality answer.

Comment: obviously the answer is n square. can you prove that?

Comment: ok I see what you mean +1

Answer (score 0):

as we can see, these are the square numbers of 1,2,3,4 and so on.
so the first number is 1^2=1
2^2=4
3^2=9
4^2=16 and so on.
for any nth term,the result is the square of it, so the pattern is n^2.

Answer (score 0):

The following is overkill for this sequence of perfect squares, but *in general...*

Every sequence with a “constant acceleration” (second common difference) $d$ has a recurrence equation $$T_n-T_{n-1}=dn+s$$ for some $s.$

- So, its closed-form expression for $T_n$ can be derived using
  [telescoping
  cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) and
  summing up the ensuing arithmetic sequence.

Expressing $d$ and $s$ in terms of $T_1, T_2$ and $T_3$ gives the unwieldy $$T_n=\left(\frac{T_1-2T_2+T_3}2\right)n^2+\left(\frac{-5T_1+8T_2-3T_3}2\right)n+\left(3T_1-3T_2+T_3\right)\\=\frac d2\,n^2+\left(\frac{-5T_1+8T_2-3T_3}2\right)n+\left(3T_1-3T_2+T_3\right).$$

Thus, such sequences are commonly called **quadratic sequences**.

- So, another method to derive the closed-form expression for $T_n$ is
  to plug $n=1,2,3$ into $$T_n=pn^2+qn+r$$ and solve simultaneously
  for $p,q$ and $r,$ or, to plug $n=1,2$ into
  $$T_n=\frac d2n^2+qn+r$$ and solve simultaneously for $q$ and $r.$

Comment: I think you're doing it all a degree lower than you should. We just tried to use your quadratic Tn formula for the succession from OP, and it didn't work properly (but a 3rd degree polynomial did). So the proper one for this should be ```Tn=an^3+bn^2+cn+d```.

Comment: @Rusca8 No, the formula for the $n$th term of the OP's sequence (whose common difference $d$ is $2$) is indeed $T_n=pn^2+qn+r,$ with $p,q,r$ being $1,0,0,$ respectively.

Comment: Oh, sorry, the one we had here was the sum of the OP's one.